# How would I specify a data table that I have set up postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I am looking to set up the backend logic for a form where it shoots information to a data table that I set up in postgresql and was wondering, how I would specify the data table that I want to send the information to?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a ModelForm.  Assuming the 'data table' you mention is the database model class, you declare the Model you are sending information to in the Meta class, as shown here:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'birth_date']

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['name', 'authors']
```

Notice where it says "model = Book" or "model = Author".  This example is from the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) on ModelForms.  You will need to instantiate your ModelForm class in your view.